# Is this the proper way to use bootstrap to change the number of elements in a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with 4 elements.
On small devices and all bigger devices, I want to display all 4 elements in the one row.
On an extra-small device I want to display them in two rows, two elements per row.
In pseudo code my HTML looks like

```
form-group form-group-xs form-group-sm
    xs-5 sm-3 elem1
    xs-7 sm-3 elem2
    xs-5 sm-3 elem3
    xs-7 sm-3 elem4
end form-groups
```

This works but it seems to me this is not the way Bootstrap was designed to work. The problem I have with it is that it relies on wrapping to put elem3 and elem4 in row 2.

Is this the proper way to use bootstrap to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a 12 column grid system you want your code to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">element 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">element 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">element 3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">element 4</div>
</div>
```

Take a look at the following example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete